# If $f'(x) = 0$ for every $x \in D$, then $f(x) = k$ for all $x \in D$, even when $D$ is not an interval.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Either give a proof or a counterexample to the following statement:
If $f : D \to R$ is a diﬀerentiable function and $f'(x) = 0$ for every $x \in D$, then $f(x) = k$ for all $x \in D$, even when $D$ is not an interval.

The proof I immediately think of involves the Mean Value Theorem, but that does require for $D$ to be an interval, if I am not mistaken. However, I feel as though this statement does not require an interval to be true. I am having issues proving it.

Comment: Is $D$ an arbitary subset of $\Bbb R$ or does it have any properties that we know of? For example is it connected?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a counterexample with $D=(0,1)\cup (2,3)$, or if you feel adventurous, with $D=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I am curious taking $D=Q$... Can you show me? (I really want to know)

Comment: @user The classical example is $$f(x) = \cases{-1 & if $x^2 < 2$\\1 & if $x^2 > 2$}$$

Comment: Thank you! I wars thinking in some like this

Answer (score 2):

If $D$ is not interval then there exists $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $D=((-\infty , c)\cap D)\cup ((c, \infty )\cap D).$ Define $$f(x) =\begin{cases} 1 \mbox{ if } x\in (-\infty , c)\cap D \\ 2\mbox{ if } x\in (c,\infty )\cap D\end{cases}$$ then $f'(x) =0$ for $x\in D$ but $f$ is not constant.